# How to make after the Click Event on the Context Menu Strip a password column on a Data Grid View C# visible?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 2 && e.Value != null)
    {
        e.Value = new String('*', e.Value.ToString().Length);
    }
}
```

---

This  works as a password protected `GridView`.
But I need after the `ClickEvent` on show password on the `ContextMenuStrip` to show particular line column password visible.

Comment: What will you do with this password once you have it as text? (Show it to user, copy to clipboard etc?)

Comment: instead of replacing password with * , Encrypt and decrypt